# how to get this json object table filter working

Tags: javascript, json

I have a website with a list of `json` objects arranged something like this:

```
 [
    {
        "a": true or false,
        "b": "information",
        "c": "information",
        "d": "information",
        "e": "information"
    },
    ...
 ]
```

The idea of this code is to print out all the objects on a table and have a checkbox which filters out the `false` objects out when needed. The site is supposed to just have the the table with unfiltered object on there, but after I added the checkbox event listener the full table list disappeared. When I check the checkbox I get the filtered objects and it keeps adding more and more of the same filtered content on the bottom of the table if I keep re-clicking it.

What am I doing wrong here? Here is the code I have:

```
var stuff = document.getElementById("stuff-info");
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'url');
ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    renderHTML(ourData);
};
ourRequest.send();

function renderHTML(data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    var filteredData = data.filter(function(element) {
        return element.a
    });
    var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=hide]");

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            for (i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
                htmlString += "<table><tr><td>" + filteredData[i].b + "</td><td>" + filteredData[i].c + "</td><td>" + filteredData[i].d + "</td><td>" + filteredData[i].e + "</td></tr>"
            }
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                htmlString += "<table><tr><td>" + data[i].b + "</td><td>" + data[i].c + "</td><td>" + data[i].d + "</td><td>" + data[i].e + "</td></tr>"
            }
        }
        stuff.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
    });
}
```

Comment: your filter says to return `element.a`. and its only one element with true or false. in first case it goes to the else loop

Comment: `it keeps adding more and more of the same`..  Well that's because that is indeed what your doing.  Either remove the old html first, or alternatively render everything and use a class to toggle visibility of the items.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to filter with CSS selector:

```css
#filter:checked ~ table .filter { display: none }
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id=filter> Filter 

<table border=1>
  <tr class=filter><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr class=filter><td>3</td><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>d</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> after I added the checkbox event listener the full table list disappeared.

All of your logic for deciding what to render is trapped inside your `onchange` event, so nothing will be drawn until a checkbox is *changed*.

> When I check the checkbox I get the filtered objects and it keeps adding more and more of the same filtered.

All of your html strings are generated with `+=` against the original `htmlString` variable trapped in the closure. So yeah, it will just keep adding more and more rows. You are also inserting the udated strings into the dom without removing the old table(s), so this will be exponential growth.

---

I think there is a great case here for higher order functions instead of `for` loops, you can use the `map` array method to transform each item in the array into a string, instead of manually iterating. This is cleaner and more maintainable.

Notice that now that the rendering logic is not mixed together with the event logic, it would be much easier to reuse the render function with some different data or different events. It's also somewhat trivial to add more transformations or filters.

```
const ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.onload = function() {
    const ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    initialRender(ourData);
};
ourRequest.open('GET', 'url');
ourRequest.send();

function filterAll() { return true; }
function filterA() { return element.a; }

function toRowString(item) {
  return `
    <tr>
      <td>${item.a}</td>
      <td>${item.b}</td>
      <td>${item.c}</td>
      <td>${item.d}</td>
      <td>${item.e}</td>
    </tr>`;
}

function renderTable(predicate, parentElement, data){
    const rows = data
        .filter(predicate)
        .map(toRowString);

    parentElement.innerHTML = `<table>${rows}</table>`;
}

function initialRender(data) {
    const stuff = document.getElementById("stuff-info");
    const checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=hide]");

    renderTable(filterAll, stuff, data);

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        renderTable( 
          event.target.checked ? filterA : filterAll,
          stuff,
          data
        );
    }
}
```